# cohomology of orthogonal (or general linear) group over finite fields

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, cohomology, group-cohomology, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{Z}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Let

$$
O(\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus k})=\{A\mid A \text{ is a } k\times k \text{ - matrix with entries  } 0,1, det(A)=\pm 1\}
$$

What is $$
H^*(BO(\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus k});\mathbb{Z})?
$$
If it cannot be computed out, can we get
$$
H^*(O(\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus k});\mathbb{Z}_2)?
$$
 or for prime $p\geq 3$,
$$
H^*(O(\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus k});\mathbb{Z}_p)?
$$

Comment: It would be better to use $GL_k(\mathbb{F}_2)$ instead of $O(\mathbb{Z}_2^{\oplus k})$. You can find computations in Chapter 1 of Knudson's "Homology of linear groups" or in Chapter VII of Adem-Milgram "Cohomology of finite groups".

Answer (score 3):

More of a long comment.

The paper you may look into is [On the Cohomology and K-Theory of the General Linear Groups Over a Finite Field](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?b=315016&b=279804)
 by Daniel Quillen.

He first shows that $$BGL(F_q) \cong F\psi^q$$ 
where $F_q$ is a field of order $q$, $\psi^q$ are the Adams operations on $BU$ and $F\psi^q$ is the homotopy equalizer of $1$ and $\psi^q$. Then he computes the cohomology rings. See Theorem 1 and Theorem 2 of the paper.

Here $$BGL(F_q) = \bigcup_k BGL_k(F_q).$$ I do not know the answer to cohomology of $BGL_k(F_q)$ for a fixed $k$.